# Limit argument in economic paper

Tags: analysis

The following appears in an economic paper, and I am entirely unsure as to how the limit was evaluated:

> $$\frac12\left[h(p)+\left(p-\frac{\partial c^A}{\partial q^A}\right)\left(h'(p)-\gamma(0)h(p)\right)\right]=0.$$
>   As $\gamma(0)\to\infty$ in the symmetric equilibrium, on the other hand, [the equation] implies that $(p-(\partial c^A/\partial q^A))\to0$.  That is, the market price [...]

Comment: I think the idea is that, if you have an expression like this:
$$
A(x)+B(x)C(x) = 0
$$
and you know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} C(x) = \pm \infty$, in order for the expression to still hold, you would need $B(x) \to 0$. Otherwise the product $B(x) \cdot C(x)$ will "blow up". If $B(x)$ doesn't approach zero, the expression wouldn't hold anymore.

Answer (score 1):

We do some manipulations on the given equality to find
\begin{align*}
\left( p - \frac{\partial c^A}{\partial q^A} \right) =& \frac{-h(p)}{h'(p)-\gamma(0) h(p)}
\end{align*}
Taking the limit $\gamma(0) \to \infty$ yields the desired result.